# getting the text from attribute value in html

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the country code of the products form this website: https://www.skincarisma.com/products/olay/fresh-effects-s-wipe-out-refreshing-make-up-removal-cloths

## [here is the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu5i7.png)

I tried

```
country = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="card-subtitle mb-2"]//img[@alt]').text
```

and

```
country = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="card-subtitle mb-2"]//img').text
```

but it failed to fetch (apparently because my code is wrong)

What should be the path?

trying: getting the coutnry code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more reliable way of getting that information would be:

```
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://www.skincarisma.com/products/olay/fresh-effects-s-wipe-out-refreshing-make-up-removal-cloths'

driver.get(url)
country = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//product-info//div[@class="card-subtitle mb-2"]//img'))).get_attribute('alt')
print(country)
```

Result:

```
US
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is contained in the alt attribute, therefore:

```
country = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="card-subtitle mb-2"]//img').get_attribute("alt")
```